# Find and replace an uppercase character from a string and keep the original match

Tags: bash, sed, tr

I need to change a string "TestString" to this format "[tT]est[sS]tring".

I tried using `sed`:

`testString="TestString"
 sed 's/\([[:upper:]]\)/[&\1]/g' <<< "$testString" | tr '[[:upper:]]' '[[:lower:]]'`

The result is:
`[tt]est[ss]tring`

I would like to ask for your help to find a way to make the second character inside the brackets upper case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use `sed` for this without having to use `tr`. The below works fine on the version from GNU

```
sed -E 's/([[:upper:]])/[\L\1\u&]/g' <<< "$testString"
```

To understand how it works

```
s/([[:upper:]])/[\L\1\u&]/g
#  ^^^^^^^^^^^              Match the uppercase character
#                ^^^^       lower case the matched letter
#                    ^^^^   upper case the matched letter
```

You could also do `s/([[:upper:]])/[\L\1\u\1]/g` because the both `\1` and `&` refer to the matching group from the search pattern.

MacOS (FreeBSD) sed doesn't support case conversion functions `\L`, `\u` by default. You can install it using `brew install gnu-sed` and invoke `gsed` to launch it.

Comment: Doesn't work on Mac OS, at least not from my testing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yes I expect not, it needs GNU `sed`

Comment: @JairusRoguel: Do a `brew install gnu-sed` and use `gsed` instead of `sed`

Comment: Perhaps `sed 's/[[:upper:]]/[\l&&]/g' file`?